# Using Cypress.Promise to get list values in test for comparisons and searches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, bluebird, coded-ui-tests

My question I know ahead of time may not be a "`best practice`" but **I promise you I won't understand the "best practice" until I can implement the question at hand and then understand why it is inefficient.**

I work with react tables and I'm trying to create helper functions based on Cypress.Promise. I've done so in the past at a previous job but I never internalized the logic behind Promises and consequentially forgot how to get values, pull strings and then return the list to a variable for the rest of the tests. And while it sounds simple to describe I'm having a difficult/frustrating time remembering how to implement it.

1. From there the plan would be to sort the list (asc & desc) via UI & confirm with Cypress.
2. Search a random name in the list and validate it's the only value in the list
3. I forgot...

But I just need a function that like let table_strings = CyPromiseFunction("table_element")

That returns a list like `["Slack","Meet","Hangouts","Messenger","Teams"]`

That I can filter & search off of.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for asking a question here. Please can you edit your question a bit - It is important to highlight - What exactly you want to know, and what you have tried to do to solve the issue yourself, to save time of the people trying to help you. The extra information like why and best practice etc can be added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear what it is you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to grab table data and use that data to validate against filtering, sorting, etc. If this is not the case, please update your answer to be more specific.

If this is what you are trying to do, then I am not sure why you need to use `Cypress.Promise` to achieve this.

If your React table uses `tbody/theader/tr/td` type structure, you could probably use the [Cypress-Get-Table](https://github.com/roggerfe/cypress-get-table) plugin to grab your table data. If nothing else, reviewing the source code could help put you on the right track.